# SonarQube Exceptions Catch

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, devops, sonarqube-scan

Hello so far I use this rule
for catching exception that are not related to SonarQube code checking.
Can you folks suggest common Exceptions that I should include if WaitforQuality gates for unknown reasons other then code...

```
   try {
        steps.timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') { steps.waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true }
    } catch (IllegalStateException exception) {
        state.setPipelineErrorMessage("${exception}")
        steps.unstable('Not a code issue. Build will be Unstable!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but the catch block that we use around the timeout block is checking for "FlowInterruptedException" (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException). That is what is thrown when the timer expires.